# Goroutine invoked in a method defined in a package does not run

Tags: go, goroutine

I am just wondering that if a goroutine invoked in a method which is defined in a package may not run.

Here is the structure my sample program:

```
sample
├── abc
│   └── abc.go
└── main.go
```

And the following is the source code of abc.go and main.go

**abc.go**

```
1 package abc
2 
3 import (
4   "fmt"
5 )
6 
7 func PrintCde() {
8   fmt.Println("Cde")
9 }
10 
11 
12 type Abc struct {}
13 
14 func (a Abc)PrintAbc() {
15   fmt.Println("Abc")
16   go PrintCde()
17   for {}
18 }
```

**main.go**

```
1 package main
2 
3 import (
4   "sample/abc"
5 )
6 
7 func main() {
8   var a abc.Abc
9   a.PrintAbc()
10 
11 }
```

Then if I run the program, I never get the string "Cde" printed on the screen.

What I can guess is the for loop in the method PrintAbc occupies the computing resources and function PrintCde never got scheduled to run.

If this is the reason, is there any other ways to prevent 
the method PrintAbc from retruning but not occupy the resources to let function printCde run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an empty/infinite `for` will generally cause this problem. For this purpose, use the empty `select{}` which is a **blocking** operation instead, and will encourage/force the runtime to swap Goroutines. Other options include increasing GOMAXPROCS or (in a real program) using something like a `sync.WaitGroup` to wait until the other Goroutine has finished processing before naturally terminating the program.

Comment: I am using sync.WaitGroup to hang the server now ! Many thanks.